# How to fix this Contact "InformalName" error for an email template deploy?

Tags: email, salesforcedx, email-template

We are getting this error on an `sfdx force source deploy` to a Developer Edition org of a `messaging:emailTemplate` that has `recipientType="Contact"`:

```
Error MyFolder/MyEmailTemplate Salutation, LastName, MiddleName, InformalName, Suffix, Id FROM Contact
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:53
```

We have no references to `InformalName` in our code and it's unclear where this query is coming from.

Comment: This may be related to this Salesforce known issue "Messaging.sendEmail() fails with "No such column 'InformalName' on entity 'Contact'" when VF email template is part of managed package".
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwWMAA0/messagingsendemail-fails-with-no-such-column-informalname-on-entity-contact-when-vf-email-template-is-part-of-managed-package#:~:text=No%20such%20column%20'InformalName'%20on%20entity%20'Contact'.,call%20for%20the%20appropriate%20names.&text=As%20a%20workaround%2C%20try%20to,Contact%20before%20calling%20the%20Messaging.

Comment: Hi @PabloFischer unfortunately the suggested work-around in that 4 year old unresolved issue won't - AFAIK - help here as it is a deployment time problem not a run time problem. I've added a "Report" to that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this error, try deploying only the email template that has the "InformalName" issue. Once you've done that, you can attempt to deploy the entire solution again, and hopefully, the error will no longer persist. I have tested that and the error is no longer happening.

To deploy the specific email template, use the following command:

```
sfdx force source deploy -p "force-app/main/default/email/namespace__MyFolder/namespace__MyEmailTemplate.email"
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the exact cause of the issue. It's likely an internal problem with Salesforce because there's no mention of "InformalName" at all, just as you mentioned.

Comment: I noticed that this issue was also happening when sending emails, and not only when deploying it. I have upgraded all emails to API 57.0 and it fixed the issue. Some of them were API 52.0 and others didn't have an API specified.